# Comment nomme-t-on la construction consistant à faire référence à un élément non encore cité ?

Tags: pronoms, constructions, figure-de-style

Quelques exemples devraient être plus parlants que le strict intitulé de la question :

> Si vous **en** avez l'audace, venez ici demain sans vos amis.

ou bien

> Quand vous **la** verrez, embrassez votre mère de ma part !

Au moment où le pronom intervient (*en* ou *la*, respectivement), l'interlocuteur ne peut pas encore effectuer la référence et doit mémoriser cette occurrence pour plus tard.

Il me semble que ça a un nom… quelqu'un saurait ça ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dans les exemples cités, il s'agit simplement de subordonnées circonstancielles. Le complément circonstanciel est un élément qui peut changer de place dans la phrase.

En français (comme en anglais) on parle d'[élément cataphorique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cataphore_%28grammaire%29): les éléments en gras dans les exemples donnés sont explicités dans la proposition principale.